# What is the point of object assigning to an empty object?

Tags: javascript

I'm asking because I saw it here:

https://github.com/bengrunfeld/react-flux-simple-app/blob/master/src/js/stores/AppStore.js

```
var AppStore = assign({}, EventEmitter.prototype, {
    emitChange: function() {
        this.emit(CHANGE_EVENT);
    }
});
```

I understand why we would assign the `EventEmitter` prototype, we want all of the functionality of the `EventEmitter`; and the last object we assign is to override the `emitChange` event. But why is the first parameter an empty object (`{}`)? Is this necessary? I've seen it done a couple times.

Comment: That's one way to create a new object. If the function expect the first parameter to be an object, you have to send one in.

Comment: But couldn't you just pass the prototype in first?

Comment: @KennyWorden: Then it would extend that prototype, which is not desirable. We only want to extend our new object.

Comment: Forgive me @Bergi, but I still do not understand - don't we want to extend the `EventEmitter`? Isn't that the whole reason we even pass the prototype as a parameter?

Comment: No, the code does create a new object (via that literal `{}`), does extend *it* with the `EventEmitter` methods, and assigns the new object to `AppStore`. If you'd leave out the new object, you'd get `AppStore === EventEmitter.prototype`, and would have your custom methods on that global object. Not what we want.

Comment: I see. Could doing `assign(new EventEmitter(), { emitChange: function(){ ... } });` accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the syntax of the assign method that takes as the first parameter the object where you want to put the methods from the second object. You can use it with an existing object but if you don't have one you pass a new empty object {} assign copy all the methods and properties there and return it modified.

Have a look at this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: What about prototypes? It says, "It uses [[Get]] on the source and [[Put]] on the target... this may make it unsuitable for merging new properties into a prototype if the merge sources contain getters..." What does that mean?